# Is block-scope buffer valid outside of the block in C

Tags: c, memory, lexical-scope

Can the following can be considered safe practice?

```
void some_func(void) {
    const char * foo;

    if (SOME_MACRO()) {
       char * foo_buf[20];
       snprintf(foo_buf,sizeof(foo_buf),"blah_%d",some_global);
       foo = foo_buf;
    } else {
       foo = "some constant string";
    }
    // do a bunch of other stuff here...
    printf("%s\n", foo);
}
```

This makes the assumption that the memory in `foo_buf` is still valid (and unchanged) outside of the block scope.   I'm concerned if there are any situations where the compiler discards or overwrites block specific memory when the block  has exited.

The reason I'd like the declaration in the block rather than in global scope is that on some platforms, `SOME_MACRO()` would resolve to a constant, in others, to an expression, so the code inside the if block can be optimized out in some cases.

Comment: NOT a good idea. "block-scope" does what it says on the can: the buffer is *not* valid outside its scope. The behaviour of your code will be undefined: it might appear to work, but may fail unpredictably/randomly/painfully and be a *big* maintenance problem.

Comment: Your title is malformed - *Is block-scope buffer valid outside of the block in c* -- the answer is yes, sometimes. What you are asking is, is buffer declared in a block valid AFTER it's lifetime?

Comment: @barny: You write that block-scope does what it says on the can but then misstate it. “Scope” is about visibility. Scope is **where** an **identifier** is visible. The concept of **when** an **object** exists is lifetime or storage duration. Lifetime is related to scope because, for objects with automatic storage duration, their lifetime ends when execution of the associated block **ends**, but not when execution merely **leaves** the block temporarily. This results in objects being completely valid and accessible outside the scope of their identifiers, as when a subroutine is called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [UB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Lifting `char * foo_buf[20];` up shouldn't give you worse code. All the function's locals are likely to be allocated at the top anyway and compilers are quite well capable of eliminating locals that get never used.

Try compiling:

```
#define UP 0
#define CONST 1

#include <stdio.h>

#if CONST
   #define SOME_MACRO() 0
#else
   int SOME_MACRO(void);
#endif

int some_global;


void some_func(void) {
    const char * foo;

    #if UP
        char foo_buf[20]; // Fixed from char *foo_buf[20];
    #endif

    if (SOME_MACRO()) {

        #if !UP
            char foo_buf[20]; //fixed from char *foo_buf[20];
        #endif

       snprintf(foo_buf,sizeof(foo_buf),"blah_%d",some_global);
       foo = foo_buf;
    } else {
       foo = "some constant string";
    }
    // Do a bunch of other stuff here...
    printf("%s\n", foo);
}
```

with with CONST set to either 0 or 1 and then changing UP to between 0 and 1.

With [GCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection), [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), or [Intel C++ Compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_C%2B%2B_Compiler), moving the declaration (by changing `UP`) doesn't make any difference, even at [-O0](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O0): See [this code at Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z9jnQD).

Answer (score 3):

> This makes the assumption that the memory in foo_buf is still valid (and unchanged) outside of the block scope

That's a big assumption.  Attempting to dereference memory to a variable that is no longer in scope invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  There is no guarantee that memory will contain what you think it will.

It's better to either define that buffer at a higher scope where it will still be valid or to allocate memory dynamically so that it remains valid.

Also, the type is not correct:

```
char * foo_buf[20];
```

This defines an array of pointers, not an array of characters.  It should be:

```
char foo_buf[20];
```

Comment: It would be better characterized as an issue of *lifetime* than one of scope.  During its lifetime, an object can be accessed (through a pointer) even though its identifier is not in scope.  Outside an object's lifetime, on the other hand, there is no object to access, and attempts to access it produce UB.